# Schedule notification to execute every day starting next week

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications, unnotificationrequest, unnotificationtrigger

**My original problem:**

When a user is setting an alarm for 19:00, I would like to show a reminder at:
19:03
19:09
19:12
In case he did not interact with the notification.

(The app should be able to run offline, so there is no way of using push notification to wake the app up for this process, and as you know, local notification do not wake the app).

So every time a user schedules a reminder, I'm acutely scheduling 4 (1 original, and 3 repeats) and if the user interacts with the notification, I remove all the rest.

The problem is, the notification is repeated every day (1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7 days a week) So if I remove all the notifications, It will not show ever again.

Is there a way of squealing a notification to start from next week every day?

**EXAMPLE:**

Today is Sunday 13:00
And I would like to schedules a notification for every Sunday on 13:01 starting tomorrow.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is an objective C code to get notification every day on same time. 
Provide ur date for scheduling notification on that time Suppose 
23 June 8:30 am then it will schedule notification on 8:30 am daily.

```
-(void)scheduleNotificationAtTime:(NSDate *)date withUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)dictData{

      self.gregorian = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];;
    NSDateComponents *components = [self.gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];

    NSDateComponents *components1 = components;
    components1.hour = components.hour;
    components1.minute = components.minute;


    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];

    NSLog(@"Hour %ld Min %ld ", hour,minute);


    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components1 repeats:YES];

    /* Set notification */

    UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
    content.body = @"Yo received notification.";
    // content.categoryIdentifier=NSNotificationC;
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
    NSString *identifier = @"LocalNotification";
    content.userInfo = dictData;
    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier
                                                                          content:content
                                                                          trigger:trigger];

    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
        }
    }];
}
```